# Script or program to conveniently show the content of .shp.xml files generated by ArcGIS

Tags: gratis, gis, metadata

Shapefiles (`.shp`) contain geospatial data and can be read by various open source programs such as [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/). Sometimes they are accompanied by a metadata file with the extension `.shp.xml` such as [this one](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/7fe687314a99607c3fd7d2100684f1bab2aa17f4/modules/plugin/shapefile/src/test/resources/org/geotools/data/shapefile/test-data/example.shp.xml). The file is generated by ESRI ArcGIS, a commercial GIS applicaiton, and the file can contain helpful information on what the data fields mean, what processing steps are done and when the accompanied shapefile was created/modified.

As the file is in a non-proprietary XML format I was hoping there is a tool that can make it convenient to read this metadata, at least more convenient then simply reading the plain XML fields. I have looked online for the terms "*.shp.xml viewer*" and "*arcgis metadata viewer*" but could not find anything helpful.